# Have feelings of Greeks changed towards European tourists because of the crisis?

Tags: greece

Until about 3 or 4 years ago I have been several times to Greece. They always are very polite and we were welcomed by them (not only at hotels/restaurants but also by others).

Since I want to go there again next year, I wonder if this might have changed because I can think that Greek don't like the EU, on the other hand they need tourism.

I'm from the Netherlands, and I know Germany has been quite reluctant for sending money towards Greece (The Netherlands and Germany are sometimes hard to differ for foreign people).

Comment: It is not possible to answer this question meaningfully, as phrased. The feelings of a few may have changed for the worse, those of others not at all, and those of others changed but not enough to affect their hospitality. Those people who would hold your government against you are not probably not the most hospitable to begin with in any country— especially toward tourists, as opposed to, say, foreign bankers visiting on business. One cannot measure "feelings" as opposed to, for example, reported incidents of violence against tourists— of which there are no significant cases I am aware of.

Comment: Feelings are feelings but money is money. :)

Comment: BTW neither the Netherlands nor Germany are part of the [North Europe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_Europe)

Comment: @rlesko Please don't suggest migration if you don't know the target site well. This often leads to a frustrating experience for the asker when the question is closed on that site, as it happened in this case.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Although it's true that there are copious amounts of anti-German rhetoric in local media, it's mostly targeted towards German politics and politicians, not Germany in general or its people. Ewald Lienen, a German football coach who has been working in Greece for a few years, was recently asked more or less the same question by the Bild and [his reply was](http://www.bild.de/sport/fussball/ewald-lienen/der-deutsche-den-die-griechen-lieben-27892418.bild.html):

> I feel no animosity or German-hatred. On the contrary, they are all very courteous and friendly to me. I was not ever insulted, because I'm from Germany.

As a tourist, even if you were misidentified as a German, you wouldn't really be at risk, at least not more at risk than if you were Greek. And the Netherlands doesn't really come up in fiery crisis related talks (and why would it?).

To generalize the answer a bit, tourists from the EU don't really have anything to fear. Yes, it's possible that you might get a snarky look (or two) if you're German, but that's about it. Greece has a very long tradition in tourism, it's part of our culture and essential to our frail economy. As choster [already mentioned](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/10738/have-feelings-of-greeks-changed-towards-northern-european-tourists-because-of-cr#comment16445_10738) there have been no reported incidents of violence against tourists since the crisis began.

If you do decide to visit Greece soon, and you happen to get into a political discussion with a Greek, just agree with whatever they tell you and you'll probably get a couple of free beers out of it ;)

Comment: I would say that a general advice is to _avoid political discussions_ whenever you're travelling.

Comment: @tohecz no politics sounds safe, but boring. I am curious if this has already been discussed on the site.

Comment: @Abe this this site is about constructive question, and any online discussion about politics is non-constructive, I'm sure it has not.

Comment: @tohecz I was referring to conversations held in person _when travelling_; I disagree that avoiding political topics in these discussions _when travelling_ is a good rule of thumb.

Comment: @tohecz: No way! I very much enjoyed hearing the Greeks' perspective on the state of things. Much better than the simplistic crap in the corporate-owned media even if they do offer only one side it's with much greater depth.

Answer (score 1):

I am from Greece and have been living outside Greece since I was 18.

Even if I would like it to be in a different way, the average Greek would "separate" the European tourists in categories which I won´t get in here (although it is interesting I think).

Also the term "European" is not always clear among the Greek population. For example the ex-Yugoslavian or Balkan tourist would not be considered in general "European" even if his country belongs to Europe. Also it is not the same thing to be from Spain or the UK.

When it comes to after and before the crisis, I really do not think that you will see any difference.

Netherlands is considered definitely friendly even if it´s too close to Germany ;)